# How long from event horizont to singularity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, time, event-horizon, singularities

I was reading Quora answers.  Someone asked how long it would take to get to the center of a black hole.  Their answer (with no explanation or calculations) was 10 minutes for a Supermassive and 6 microseconds for a stellar mass.

So - I would like to see what the actual time is...

For a stellar mass BH of 5 solar masses.  If I cross the event horizon at a leisurely 1 meter per second (in my plane of reference) how long till reach the singularity?

For a supermassive BH of 1 million solar masses, how long would it take me at the same speed?

And how are these calculations made?

Comment: Why don't you make the question about *how* one estimates the time interval instead of just memorizing facts?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/403556/55662 and https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1029 both have an equation for proper time intervals, but don't necessarily address the "how are the calculations made" question.

Comment: The [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator) (which I've linked for you a while ago) can answer questions like that.

Comment: BTW, you can't cross the EH of a 5 solar mass BH at 1 m/s. The freefall speed approaches *c*, so your rocket needs insane acceleration to counteract that as you approach the BH, and no rocket will help as you actually cross the EH. Also, the BH has a Schwarzschild radius of ~14.766 km, and the tidal force at 133 km is sufficient to rip apart a 1 m long bar of A36 steel (falling vertically). See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631427/123208